# Using CSS to create a word portion lift

Tags: html, css, effects

I am trying to create a specific effect for a logo, but I dont really have an idea how this is going to work.

Here is a sketch I did in photoshop:

http://s28.postimg.org/nrb3k6grh/effect.gif

So my idea is - I have 2 divs on top of one another, one containing a graphic and under it, one containing a word. So I want to make the top div dissapear on hover and when the bottom one is shown I want to lift the "ord" part of "word" (for example) up a bit using a  or something.. How can I achieve this?

I am not sure about the two divs part though. If there is a better way of doing this, please share.

Thanks!

Comment: can you show us your code in jsfiddle.net

Comment: No code yet, sorry, I will come back later in this case.

Comment: You can also upload your image to any image uploading site: http://imgur.com, etc... and paste the link in your question.

Comment: Just did. Have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [this](http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/xGHhC) works for you

HTML

```
 <a href="" class="logo">
    W<span class="text">ord</span>
  <span class="overlay"></span>
</a>
```

CSS

```
 .logo {
  color: red;
  font-size: 60px;
  font-family: arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
.overlay {
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: red;
  opacity: 1;

}
.logo:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 0
}
.logo:hover {
  background: none
}
.logo .text {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  -moz-transition: top 0.5s 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s 0.5s;
  transition: top 0.5s 0.5s;
}
.logo:hover .text {
  top: -30px;
}
```

Comment: This works, but my idea is not for the text and the background of the div to have the same color. I meant that it should be like 2 cards on top of one another, and when you hover over the top, it dissapears and then the bottom starts with the word lift.

Comment: Tes, this is more like it. But one more question - can I wrap the word and the div into a anchor tag so it can become a link? Or this is against w3c standards?

Comment: Thanks! Aaaand one more thing - is using divs for this the best practice, or is there a leaner way?

Comment: @Tushar your DEMO have some glitches; see in your DEMO when moving mouse at the right side of the box; the text by default appear at top, Also you are using unnecessary extra div. which not required

Comment: @KheemaPandey I am not able to see such issue. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: its very hard to explain..just do some random hovering on red box. I've check the Demo on FF 30

Comment: http://codepen.io/tusharbandal/pen/xGHhC can you check it know I have added linear to the  transition.

Answer (score 0):

I've used  two div in this Demo. Have a look at the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/cazojixa/1/edit)**.

**CSS Code is**

```
.main{position:relative;}
.logo{
background:url("http://placehold.it/100x100") no-repeat; 
width:100px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
.text{
color:Blue; font-size:5vh; 
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0;
z-index:1;}

.logo:hover{ 
visibility:hidden;
opacity:0; 
transition:visibility 0.5s linear 0.5s, opacity 0.5s linear;
}

div.main:hover .text span{display:inline-block;color:red;
transform: translate(0,-10px); transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

**HTML Code is**

```
<div class="main">
  <div class="logo"><!-- To make SEO compactable Logo Text can be type here --></div>
  <div class="text">L<span>ogo</span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using CSS to create a word portion lift

Using these code lines you can use lift function on anywhere you want to use in your HTML

```css
.card-lift--hover:hover /*card lift effect*/
{
    transition: all .15s ease;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="testimonial card-lift--hover">
  <h2>Hello World</h2>
</div>
```